# $k$ times integrateable and still diverging limit with L'Hospital's rule backwards

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Given some $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that have poles around $x=a$, I want to evaluate the limit

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$

Using reversed L'Hospital's rule.

The idea is that if

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f^{(-1)}(x)}{g^{(-1)}(x)}$$

is also of indefinite forms, then by L'Hospital's rule, it is equivalent to the original limit.  ($f^{(-k)}$ is the $k$th antiderivative of $f$)

To avoid the scenario of the constant of integration having any effect, only consider functions that diverge to $\pm\infty$ around $x=a$.

Strangely, I have found that just because the function diverges does not mean the antiderivative diverges.  For example:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\ln(x)=\pm\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}x(\ln(x)-1)=0$$

More generally, for some function $f(x)$ that has pole around $x=a$, there is some $k$ such that $f^{(-k)}(x)$ does not have a pole around $x=a$.

Here is what I am thinking:

---

Suppose $f(x)$ has a pole around $x=a$.  So does $f^{(-1)}(x)$, and $f^{(-2)}(x)$, etc., but it does not have a pole for $f^{(-[k+1])}(x)$ around $x=a$.  I wish to say that $f(x)$ has a pole of degree $k$, since all $k$ antiderivatives have a pole.

Suppose the same for $g(x)$, but $g(x)$ has a pole of degree $n$ instead of $k$.

Then,

$$k>n\implies\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\pm\infty$$

$$k<n\implies\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$

And I don't know about the case $k=n$, other than the fact that if the limit is finite and non-zero, then $k$ must equal $n$.

The motivation is that applying L'Hospital's rule without algebraic manipulation or anything else is insufficient to solving any limit of this kind.

---

I honestly have no idea if the above is true, but as far as I've looked, there isn't anything about what I've thought of.  I have no explanation as to why this is the case, and if anyone could disprove, prove, or provide links to where this has been seen, that'd be wonderful.

I'm also interested in the idea of a function that has a pole with infinite degree, but I cannot construct such an example.

My last thought is that this could possibly be a comparison to $x^{-k}$, whose pole is of degree $k$, but even then, the comparison seems very assuming.

(small statement:  I think the degree that I speak of is equivalent to the order of the pole, but the connection still isn't clear, I don't know how these ideas connect, and I'm not at all familiar with poles to the degree someone taking Real Analysis is.)

Comment: Which antiderivatives of $f,g$ are you talking about when you say $f^{-1}$.

Comment: I think you are trying to use L'Hospital in incorrect way. L'Hospital allows you to infer the limit of $f/g$ on the basis of limit of $f'/g'$ under certain circumstances. You are however trying to infer limit of $f/g$ on basis of limit of $f^{-1}/g^{-1}$. This is not going to work at all.

Comment: Note further that the idea of a pole is coming from complex analysis and real analysis does not need the idea of poles. BTW a function with pole of infinite degree is $e^{1/x}$ around $x = 0$.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I meant $f$, but everything for $f$ applies to $g$ as well.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I know this is probably not going to work well, but I wish to know how it would work out anyways.  As far as I have tried for simple things, it seems to work.  And $e^{1/x}$ doesn't have a pole at $x=0$ as far as I understand.  Maybe at $0^-$.  Perhaps you meant $e^{-1/x^2}$?